# Les enfants de mes cousins ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, enfants

Avec l'augmentation de la durée de vie des grands-parents et des arrières-grands-parents, les familles comptent de plus en plus de membres au fil des générations.

Les lieux de communication sociale sur internet permettent de garder un contact plus solide et plus durable avec les personnes moins proches de la famille.

Les gens fréquentent plus souvent leur cousins. Et leurs enfants. Les fils de mes frères et sœurs sont mes neveux, leurs filles sont mes nièces.

Par quel nom puis-je désigner les enfants de mes cousins et de mes cousines ?

Je propose *nouvin* et *nouvine* (*nouvins* et *nouvines*).

Et de la même façon que mes petits-neveux et mes petites-nièces sont les enfants de mes neveux et nièces, la logique voudrait que les enfants de mes nouvins et nouvines soient mes *petits-nouvins* et *petites-nouvines*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pourquoi inventer un nouveau mot ? Le concept n'est pas nouveau. L'augmentation de la durée de vie ne change rien aux rapports qu'on peut avoir avec les enfants de ses cousins, il n'y a qu'une génération d'écart. Historiquement, c'est plutôt le contraire : les gens avaient autrefois plus tendance à garder contact avec leurs cousins, et donc avec les enfants de leurs cousins.

Les enfants de mes cousins sont mes **[petits-cousins](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/petit-cousin)**. Les petits-enfants de mes cousins sont mes **[arrière-petits-cousins](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/arri%C3%A8re-petit-cousin)**. (Les traits d'union sont parfois omis.)

Je ne connais pas de mot réciproque (pour désigner les cousins de mes parents ou de mes grands-parents), par contre. Je pense que beaucoup de gens ont indépendamment inventé le terme *grand-cousin*, et le sens se devine, mais ce n'est pas du tout standard.

Comment: Oui, mais **nouvin** c'est plus joli que _petit-cousin_.

Comment: Pour les cousins de mes parents j'ai toujours entendu dire *petit-cousin*, même s'ils sont plus grands.

Comment: Si je devais avoir une formule consacrée pour le cousin d'un de mes parents, je pense que j'emploierais le terme "arrière-cousin"...

Comment: Je profite pour signaler que ces définitions de *petit-cousin* et d'*arrière-petit-cousin* sont celles données par le dictionnaire de l'Académie Française : https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P1808 , https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A2635

Answer (score 12):

On peut utiliser le terme "neveux/nièces [à la mode de Bretagne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent%C3%A9_%C3%A0_la_mode_de_Bretagne)" pour les enfants de cousins, et "oncles/tantes à la mode de Bretagne" pour les cousins des parents.

Answer (score 10):

Complément à [la réponse de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3132/7224) : Wikipédia documente assez bien [le mot « cousin »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_(famille)) et propose une illustration assez claire des relations :

[image: Cousins]

D'après ce schéma, l'enfant de mon cousin (germain) est un cousin germain éloigné au 1er degré, ainsi que le cousin de ma mère. L'enfant de ce dernier est mon cousin issu de germains.

« Petit-cousin » est un rang plus loin encore (rouge). Il est à noter que le Wiktionnaire est d'accord avec Gilles concernant [la définition de « petit-cousin »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/petit-cousin), le faisant ainsi correspondre avec « cousin germain éloigné au premier degré » sur la figure précédente (et *nouvin* dans la proposition de l'OP).

Remarque annexe : l'oncle de ma mère est quant à lui mon grand-oncle.

Cette solution a l'avantage de couvrir tous les cas (*nouvin* ne correspondant qu'à la troisième colonne). Elle a l'inconvénient d'utiliser le même terme pour plusieurs cases.

À ma connaissance cependant, hormis pour des généalogistes qui de toute façon traceront un arbre pour s'assurer que la situation est bien comprise, ce niveau de distinction est rarement usité. Dans la vie de tous les jours, j'utilise « cousins » aussi bien pour les miens que pour ceux de mes parents et les enfants de ces derniers, et je parle des « enfants de mes cousins » pour les enfants de mes cousins directs.

Answer (score 2):

On peut aussi dire "*cousins de deuxième génération*". L'avantage est que ceci marchera avec leurs enfants ("*cousins de troisième génération*"), leurs petits-enfants ("*quatrième génération*"), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Je suis d'une famille très large (bretonne, comme par hasard) où les réunions de famille à 300, 500 voire 800 personnes sont régulières. On parle de neveux et de nièces si il y a une génération d'écart, petit-neveux, arrières-petits-neveux selon les générations, et cousins si on est de la même génération, ou si le décalage de générations fait qu'on a le même age (j'ai des oncles de 5 ans, des neveux de ma grand mère).

Je trouve cela adapté car les situations font qu'on a plus forcément intérêt à distinguer les degrés.

Answer (score -2):

Pour moi, mes petit(e)s-cousin(e)s sont les petits-enfants du frère/de la soeur de mon grand-père/ma grand-mère.

Comment: Je ne suis pas le downvoter, mais il est vrai que ceci aurait plutôt dû être un commentaire sur la réponse appropriée. Ceci dit, d'après le Wiktionnaire, la proposition de Gilles est juste, et d'après Wikipédia, ni lui ni vous n'avez raison (cf. [ma réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14737/7224)).