# Comment écrit-on lorsqu'un nom est préfixé deux fois ?

Tags: orthographe, trait-d-union, préfixes

Ma question est liée à l'orthographe et à la position des traits d'union.

Par exemple lorsqu'il y a un titre sous un plus gros titre on le nomme « *sous-titre* ». Mais si on a un sous-titre sous le sous-titre, est-ce que c'est un *sous-sous titre* ? Ou peut-être un *sous-sous-titre* ?

Y a-t-il une règle ou convention liée à cela ?

Comment: Il me semble que cette question (de vocabulaire) concerne plus particulièrement la mise en page, pas la grammaire.

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Intuitivement, je dirais quand même qu'à partir des sous-sous-titres, on rentre surtout dans le domaine des mauvaises pratiques éditoriales. Tu veux peut-être employer [chapeau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapeau_(typographie)). Ça me fait penser à la question sur les [arrière-petit-cousins](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/les-enfants-de-mes-cousins), pour la surcomposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En français les préfixes peuvent se souder à un nom (*aéroglisseur*, *surréalisme*, *contrepoids*…), ou bien se lier à eux à l'aide d'un tiret (*sous-titre*, *non-violence*, *contre-pied*…), l'usage varie, mais dans aucun cas les préfixes ne constituent un mot à eux seuls.

Le préfixe *sous-* semble  toujours relié à un nom par un tiret (cf. [la liste du wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sous-)). Apposé a un nom *X*, cela donne *sous-X*. Les doubles préfixes sont possibles, par exemple l'orthographe *anti-sous-marin* semble prédominante. De façon similaire, *sous-titre* étant un nom, *sous-sous-titre* est concevable, mais dans un texte littéraire je pense que  *sous-titre de second niveau* serait plus approprié.

En revanche *sous-sous titre* est clairement mal formé et difficilement compréhensible, tout comme le serait *anti-sous marin*.

Pour finir, un préfixe qui normalement est soudé au nom (comme *anti-*, qui donne *antibiotique*, *anticonstitutionnel*…, ou *auto-*, qui donne *automobile*, *autoportrait*…), est parfois flanqué d'un tiret pour éviter certaines juxtapositions de lettres (comme dans *anti-inflationniste*, *auto-intoxication*…) et il l'est aussi dans le cas où le nom préfixé contient lui-même un tiret. C'est pour cela qu'on écrit *anti-sous-marin*, et on peut penser également à *auto-sous-titrage*.

Comment: Eh, on peut travailler sur un bateau et s'opposer au système monétaire, je ne vois pas le problème :p

Comment: Je note que mon correcteur d'orthographe accepte *sous-auto-sous-non-truc* sans broncher, mais ça ne marche qu'avec certains préfixes.